# Sencha Touch List component

Tags: list, web-applications, extjs, sencha-touch

Does anybody knows if it is possible to add "subtitles" (the light gray text underneath the name of the item) to lists in Sencha Touch? and what about images? For the subtitles an example would be like when on the iPod music menu you get the song name and underneath info about the artist, and the images like the Flixster app for movies.

Here's my list:

```
Ext.regModel('Contact', {
fields: ['firstName', 'lastName']
});

var store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
model : 'Contact',
root: 'images',
sorters: 'firstName',

getGroupString : function(record) {
return record.get('firstName')[0];
},

data: [
{firstName: 'Tommy', lastName: 'Maintz'},
{firstName: 'Rob', lastName: 'Dougan'},
{firstName: 'Ed', lastName: 'Spencer'},
{firstName: 'Jamie', lastName: 'Avins'},
{firstName: 'Aaron', lastName: 'Conran'},
{firstName: 'Dave', lastName: 'Kaneda'},
{firstName: 'Michael', lastName: 'Mullany'},
{firstName: 'Abraham', lastName: 'Elias'},
{firstName: 'Jay', lastName: 'Robinson'}
]
});

var list = new Ext.List({
fullscreen: true,
itemTpl : '{firstName} {lastName}',
grouped : true,
indexBar: false,

store: store
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can pretty much put anything you want into the list using the itemTpl using HTML/CSS for styling

Have a look at the code below, I have just put some extra text in and an image underneath, you can style this with CSS for your desired layout!

Hope that helps!

```
Ext.setup({
          // We don't need to these sencha config options as PhoneGap takes care of this for us
          //tabletStartupScreen: '../tablet_startup.png',
          //phoneStartupScreen: '../phone_startup.png',
          //icon: 'icon.png',
          //glossOnIcon: false,

          onReady: function() {

          Ext.regModel('Contact', {
                       fields: ['firstName', 'lastName']
                       });

          var store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
                                             model : 'Contact',
                                             root: 'images',
                                             sorters: 'firstName',

                                             getGroupString : function(record) {
                                             return record.get('firstName')[0];
                                             },

                                             data: [
                                                    {firstName: 'Tommy', lastName: 'Maintz'},
                                                    {firstName: 'Rob', lastName: 'Dougan'},
                                                    {firstName: 'Ed', lastName: 'Spencer'},
                                                    {firstName: 'Jamie', lastName: 'Avins'},
                                                    {firstName: 'Aaron', lastName: 'Conran'},
                                                    {firstName: 'Dave', lastName: 'Kaneda'},
                                                    {firstName: 'Michael', lastName: 'Mullany'},
                                                    {firstName: 'Abraham', lastName: 'Elias'},
                                                    {firstName: 'Jay', lastName: 'Robinson'}
                                                    ]
                                             });

          var list = new Ext.List({
                                  fullscreen: true,
                                  itemTpl : '<div>{firstName} {lastName}</div><div>{firstName} Or some other info</div><div><img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/092108e1e1c3c7848d678022cc40010e?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG" alt="My image"></div>',
                                  grouped : true,
                                  indexBar: false,

                                  store: store
                                  });

          }



});
```

Answer (score 0):

i know the answer

```
    Ext.application({
          launch: function() {
Ext.regModel('Contact', {
   fields: ['firstName', 'lastName']
});

var store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
   model: 'Contact',
   sorters: 'lastName',

   getGroupString: function(record) {
       return record.get('lastName')[0];
   },

   data: [
       {firstName: 'Tommy',   lastName: 'Maintz'},
       {firstName: 'Rob',     lastName: 'Dougan'},
       {firstName: 'Ed',      lastName: 'Spencer'},
       {firstName: 'Jamie',   lastName: 'Avins'},
       {firstName: 'Aaron',   lastName: 'Conran'},
       {firstName: 'Dave',    lastName: 'Kaneda'},
       {firstName: 'Jacky',   lastName: 'Nguyen'},
       {firstName: 'Abraham', lastName: 'Elias'},
       {firstName: 'Jay',     lastName: 'Robinson'},
       {firstName: 'Nigel',   lastName: 'White'},
       {firstName: 'Don',     lastName: 'Griffin'},
       {firstName: 'Nico',    lastName: 'Ferrero'},
       {firstName: 'Nicolas', lastName: 'Belmonte'},
       {firstName: 'Jason',   lastName: 'Johnston'}
   ]
});

var list = new Ext.List({
   fullscreen: true,
   itemTpl: '{firstName} <strong>{lastName}</strong>',
   grouped     : true,
   indexBar    : true,
   store: store,
   hideOnMaskTap: false
});
    Ext.Viewport.add(list);
}
});
```